# View Karma Test Output in a Browser?

Tags: karma-runner

I'm new to Karma, but I'm wondering how to view its output in a browser (much like the way one interacts with Jasmine, when a runner.html file is present).

I watched the introductory screencast and I understand how to view test outputs in a console window, but in my browser, I get almost no content for Karma except

> Karma - connected

Please advise!  I would like to avoid having to maintain a separate runner.html file, since the Karma configuration file already requires me to include all necessary script links.

Comment: On my Linux box Karma also opens Chromium and says it is connected but it then instantly closes the browser. And yes the singleRun is false in the Karma configuration.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem @StephaneEybert, did you solve it?

Comment: @ChrisFletcher I changed from Chrome to PhantomJS in the test/karma.conf.js file, having this:     browsers: [
      'PhantomJS'
//      'Chrome'
    ],

Answer (score 27):

AFAIK, the previous two answers are correct in that you'll want to run the tests in a browser; click DEBUG and view the output in the console.

Politely contradicting the previous answer, I regularly do this and step-through debug with full variable interaction using Karma.

The proper answer to your question, because what you want is pretty HTML based output, is "no."  However, this plugin for karma may give you the results you desire.

https://npmjs.org/package/karma-html-reporter

Comment: Thanks I should have mentioned that you need to open the console to see anything at all, not just to debug the tests. I should check out that reporter.

Answer (score 10):

You need to run it with `singleRun = false` in  `karma.conf.js` and then click the button on the top corner that says "DEBUG". Then you should see the output and it won't disappear or close. You will also be able to use the console to debug.

Worth noting that debugging e2e tests isn't that easy because they are "future" based so you won't be able to intercept values (afaik).

Comment: This isn't working for me @Chris, I know this is an old answer but do you have any suggestions as to why this might be the case?

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while and I have not been using Karma as often lately. A lot has likely changed.

Answer (score 7):

Hi In my case I solved this problem by installing `karma-jasmine-html-reporter` and putting it in reporters array.

- Install `npm i -D karma-jasmine-html-reporter`
- add 'kjhtml' in your reporter.
- add `client:{clearContext:false}`

```js
var gulpConfig = require('./build/build.conf')();
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        basePath: './',
        plugins: [
          // all other plugins
          'karma-jasmine-html-reporter'
        ],
        colors: true,
        client: {
            clearContext: false    // will show the results in browser once all the testcases are loaded
        },
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'jasmine-sinon', 'sinon'],
        files: [].concat(
            gulpConfig.deps.lib,
            'js/**/*mother*.js',
            'js/**/*mother.*.js',
            'js/**/*.tests.js'
        ),
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        reporters: ['kjhtml', 'progress', 'coverage'],
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to open the Javascript console in your browser.  Karma creates a log entry for each test, including the result.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to display [HTML5 Web Notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) with Karma so I wrote something quick to get it to work with Karma version 0.11. Might behave slightly different with other versions. I load this script in with the rest of my application scripts, it will store the karma test results and after completion it will determine the success of the test and then reset to the original karma functions so they're not changed when this script gets run again.

```
// store all my test results
var results = [];
// Wrap the karma result function
var resultFunc = window.__karma__.result;
window.__karma__.result = function(result){
    // run the original function
    resultFunc(result);
    // push each result on my storage array
    results.push(result);
}

// wrap the karma complete function
var completeFunc = window.__karma__.complete;
window.__karma__.complete = function(result){
    // run the original function
    completeFunc(result);
    // determine success
    var success = results.every(function(r){ return r.success });

    if (success) {
        // display a success notification
    }
    else {
        // display a test failure notification
    }

    // reset the result function
    window.__karma__.result = resultFunc;
    // reset the complete function
    window.__karma__.complete = completeFunc;
}
```